# Nested intervals and $\lim_{n \to \infty} |M| = 1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Considering a sequence $(M_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ of non-empty and compact subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ such that $M_1 \supset M_2 \supset M_3 \supset \ldots$. Furthermore define

\begin{align}
d(M) := \text{max}\{|z-w| : z,w \in M\}.
\end{align}

The sequence above fulfills $\lim_{n \to \infty} d(M_n) = 0$.

Does this alone imply that
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} |M_n| = 1,
\end{align}
where $|M_n|$ denotes the cardinality of $M_n$?

Comment: Of course not, you can choose $M_n$ identical to each other to see the counter example.

Comment: No. Let $M_n$ be the closed disk of radius $1+\frac1n$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you for your quick respone. I edited the question, since I forgot an important fact. Does it change anything?

Comment: This can't be true. Take the closed disks of radius 1/n; each will be uncountably infinite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}M_n$. Your hypotheses imply that $|M|=1$, but it’s entirely possible that $|M_n|=\mathfrak{c}$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, in which case $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}|M_n|=\mathfrak{c}$.

The sets $M_n$ are compact, so the [Cantor intersection theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_intersection_theorem) ensures that $M\ne\varnothing$. If $x,y\in M$, and $x\ne y$, the hypotheses imply that $\operatorname{diam}M_n<|x-y|$ for some $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, contradicting the fact that $x,y\in M_n$. Thus, $M=\{x\}$ for some $x\in\Bbb C$. But if

$$M_n=\left\{z\in\Bbb C:|z|\le 1+\frac1n\right\}$$

for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, then $|M_n|=|\Bbb C|=\mathfrak{c}$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}|M_n|=\mathfrak{c}$.